# MPI Newbie - some questions on how 'mpirun' works and process management

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, mpi

First of all, I'm not a programmer by profession but I have to program a code for my project (I have some proficiency in C++ and python though). I came in here often when I got stuck, and most of the time got nice solutions from here, but now I have essential questions on MPI programming, else I couldn't really proceed until I know the concepts of it.

Here is my description of problems,

I would like to create a code for an algorithm for a scientific calculation. The code can be divided into 2 parts.

**A.)** Matrix-vector multiplication and inversion of a matrix. This part is relatively straightforward and I even have my own working MPI code for this part

**B.)** Calling an external MPI-ready program for a more complicated calculation (This part should also be simple, as it's simply calling a UNIX command line).

The problem I'm having is how to join these 2 parts together? My algorithm goes like this,

> ```
> for k in specified range
>    dividing a state vector of size 6NMx1 into M blocks, let each of M nodes handle these.
>    Manipulate a state vector of size 6NMx1 according to A.) in parallel
>    After A.) is done, run B.) using M nodes in parallel /* THIS IS WHERE I GOT STUCK */
>    Update state vector
> end for
> ```

To run B.), I have to use mpirun to call a UNIX command,

```
mpirun -np #PPN my_app > some_output
```

The questions I have are,

1. How does 'mpirun' actually work? Does it spawn new processes upon calling?
2. Let's say if I'm using M cluster compute nodes, and each one has 16 processors per node, if I use only 1 process of the node to call the above UNIX command, will it generate 16 more processes? If so, I will end up with 256M processes running in total, am I correct?
3. My main goal is to use each compute node handles a block in the system vector (blocks are independent, with size 6Nx1), and will use numbers from each block as an input for B.) I'm working with clusters, so when I submit my job, I have to define number of nodes beforehand, and I strictly want each node to also run B.) in parallel after A.) is done. Are there any suggestions on how to do this using MPI? Some people told me to write codes separately for A.) and B.), and use a python script to control them at the top layer, so it should look like..

Python script:

```
for k in specified range
   mpirun A.) --> This is straightforward for me
   mpirun B.)
end for
```

Pseudocode for B.)

```
/* THIS PROGRAM SHOULD HAVE 16M PROCESSES */
if rank % 16 == 0
   mpirun -np 16 my_app > output
end if
/* I WANT M CALLS TO THIS PROGRAM IN PARALLEL */
MPI_COMM.BARRIER
```

Do you think this scheme will use 16M process in parallel for B.)? If there are better ways to implement B.) than this, or even better, to wrap it in the same code as A.), please suggest me!

3.) This is my prototype code, so I don't really care about efficiency. I just need it to work, and I will care about optimization later on.

If my descriptions are confusing, please ask me and I will come back and clarify. Thank you for your time, and I really appreciate your helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Mpirun is just a command that runs the number of jobs that you required in the option command line, it will probably detect what kind of machine you have and work with.

It's complicated to answer to the second question because if you are using a cluster with multiple nodes you should probably work with a dedicated protocol. For example, with slurm you run your program through a sbatch protocol which is like:

```
// number of proc on one node
#SBATCH -n 2
// number of node
#SBATCH -N 4

run ./a.out
```

That means you will run your program on 4 nodes with 2 procs on each nodes.

I don't really know about the following cause it's a lil bit confuse for me but maybe you should reconsider your problem with something else. You don't need MPI if you are working within a node but you should use openMP.

MPI is needed if you are working with a non-shared memory, within a node that's not the case.

I hope it can help you in your work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Yes, my cluster uses SLURM scheduler. Does this mean I actually have to specify number of processors and nodes exactly upon running the program in the .msub file? So, really, do I need to just write an .msub file instead of directly refer to my program in the second code?

Comment: Hey. Yes if you are using SLURM, you just need to write a script to run your program and specify what proc and node you require. But it might be needed to add some configuration in your code depending on how many proc and nodes you are running your program (if it's not generic). Here's some info about SLURM, maybe you can find some answer:

Comment: web site: http://slurm.schedmd.com   - quick introduction to SLURM:  https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/slurm/slurm.pdf